# multiple database inside a single php website page

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to use more than one database inside an single website ?
All were i seen that only one db inside a website .Is it possible to use more than one database inside a single php website ? If it's possible please give an example    with php and mysql .

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can access any of your databases in PHP if you enter the correct authentication (host, username, and password).

- An example of this: Having more than one database connection script and including the connection scripts in a single PHP file, thus using and potentially interacting with more than one database within a single PHP file.